# Force third window to the front from Java

Tags: java, focus, keyevent, user32, hwnd

I am developing a Java application, and I want to take and save an screenshot from a concrete window which I dont have access to the code. To do so, I have the following function:

```
    public void nextStep(){
        final MyUser32 user32 = MyUser32.INSTANCE;
        user32.EnumWindows(new MyUser32.WNDENUMPROC() {

            public boolean callback(HWND hwnd, Pointer userData) {
                byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
                user32.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, windowText, 512);
                String wText = Native.toString(windowText);

            if(wText.contains(MyString)){
                System.out.println("Window hdwn: " + hwnd + " - Text: " + wText);
                User32.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(hwnd, WinUser.SW_MAXIMIZE);
                User32.INSTANCE.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
               //I ve tried with setFocus as well and does not work either
                capture();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }, null);
}
```

The capture() method is the following:

```
public void capture(){
    Robot robot;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No robot");
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    try {
        capt = (BufferedImage) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
        ImageIO.write(capt, "png", new File("captura.png"));
    } catch (HeadlessException | UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And MyUser32 class is the following:

```
public interface MyUser32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    MyUser32 INSTANCE = (MyUser32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", MyUser32.class);
    interface WNDENUMPROC extends StdCallCallback {
        boolean callback(HWND hwnd, Pointer arg);
    }
    boolean EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer arg);
    int GetWindowTextA(HWND hwnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
}
```

If the variable MyString has a value, lets say, "paint" what this part of the code would do is:

-List all the active windows

-For each one containing the string "paint" in the title:

*Print its information, like the title and the hwnd

*Bring it Maximized to the front

*Set it as the Foreground Window (again, yes)

*Apply the capture() method, which does:

First presses alt+up, which maximizes the focused window, and then presses alt+Capt. Screen, which captures only the focused window and saves it in the clipboard. Finally, it saves the capture as "captura.png"

It works well for the most of the windows, like paint or google chrome, but it doesnt work well for the window I am interested in capturing. Sometimes it brings it to the front and sometimes it doesnt, without any apparent reason, but it never gets maximized or captured, even though alt+up and alt+captScreen work perfectly fine from my physical keyboard, and the information of the window gets printed well always.

Does someone know how can I force that third window to get the focus? I guess the problem is there, but I might be wrong. Also, I dont have any other window running that is keeping the focus forcedly.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not use AspectJ to allow you to change the behavior of the program. So, you could have a button in your program that sends a message to this other program, and force it then to be maximized and in front, or, have it just take a screenshot of the screen at that point.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I know nothing about this AspectJ, I m just googling it. The first doubt that comes to my mind is which message to send, due to right now I m usind the user32 library which is supposed to manage these things but it does not work. Also, my problem is that once the window comes up, I cannot capture it itself with the keyevent functions, the program just breaks saving the data obtained from the clipboard. I want to do OCR over this window, thats why I need to capture the window itself.
Thanks